# How to scroll to next div with class?

Tags: jquery

I am loading divs with ajax, how do I scroll to newly added elements?

On load html

```
<div class="wrapClass">
    <content />
</div>
```

Then when I click on load more button i get:

```
<div class="wrapClass">
    <content />
</div>
<div class="wrapClass">
    <content />
</div>
<div class="wrapClass">
    <content />
</div>
```

I need to scroll to the newly added div with class `wrapClass`

I have a working callback so I know when the new div is appended which is:

```
jQuery.fn.almComplete = function(alm){.. });
```

Comment: could always do a default of current active or something and then do a `next()` from the current finding `.wrapClass` and then do a `scrollTop()`

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Identifying the element that you want to scroll to, or the actual scrolling itself? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id='newDiv'>new data</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: +=$('#newDiv').height()
})
```

or

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(window).position().top += $('#newDiv').height()
})
```